# Why does storing an 32-bit unsigned int value of -1 in SQLite DB and reading it back result in the value getting changed to half?

Tags: c++, sqlite, visual-c++, truncate, unsigned-integer

In its simplest form, below is a pseudo code of the problem:

```
enum E { VALUE = -1; }
uint32_t value = VALUE;  // signed to unsigned conversion without typecasting
SQLiteDB.INSERT(<table containing `value`>);
SQLiteDB.SELECT(<same table as above>);
```

In the DB, I see that the `value` is stored as `4294967295` (i.e. `0xFFFFFFFF`) which is correct. But when the value is read from the DB, it is truncated as `2147483647` (`0x7FFFFFFF`) which is appx half of the original value.

Why is that? How to solve this problem?

*Update*: As informed above, the value 0xFFFFFFFF is visible in SQLite properly, but when read in the `uint32_t` back, it's truncated. Possibly is it a data loss?
Below is an image seen with SQLiteBrowser on the actual data.

[image]

---

Related but not duplicate:

- [Casting negative integer to larger unsigned integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21769068/casting-negative-integer-to-larger-unsigned-integer)
- [What happens if I assign a negative value to an unsigned variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711522/what-happens-if-i-assign-a-negative-value-to-an-unsigned-variable)

Comment: SQLite3 always stores integers as signed 64-bit values. It will not convert `0xFFFFFFFF` to `0x7FFFFFFF`. The problem is probably in `SQLiteDB` class driver (which I don't know about).

Comment: How are you storing the value in the database and how are you retrieving it? Need actual code, not pseudocode.

Comment: @prapin, Yes. SQLite is storing as it is. Just while reading back in `uint32_t` the most significant bit becomes from 1 to 0. This possibly results in the value getting half. Why is that?

Comment: @Shawn, the actual code may not be possible to give here as it's done via another library. However, in a nutshell as edited in the post, the data is stored properly within the DB. While reading to `uint32_t` probably the sign-bit is reset to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue.
I am using a library code to read the DB tables. Which gets the values in form of string properly. Further `std::stoi()` is used for converting to the desired `uint32_t`.

Now `4294967295` is **too big** of an integer for an `std::stoi()`. In fact in Ubuntu 64-bit machine, it throws an exception. However in Windows, somehow it truncates by resetting the sign bit to 0 and hence it becomes `2147483647`. May be this is a consistent undefined behaviour. :-)

Instead of `std::stoi()`, if we use `std::stol()` or `::strtoul()`, then that resolves the problem and the value is read correctly as `4294967295` to a `uint32_t` variable.